# problem connecting to melpa packages

Tags: init-file, package, package-repositories

I'm new to emacs, and I'm having problems when trying to set up my `init.el` file to connect to the melpa packages site. I'm using MacOS Big Sur version 11.6, and Emacs version 26.2 (9.0) since there were some problems installing the latest version.

In the `init.el` file I have put:

```
(require ‘package)
(setq package-enable-at-startup nil)
(add-to-list ‘package-archives
             ‘(“melpa” . “https://melpa.org/packages/“))
(package-initialize)
```

I get the following error message when M-x package-refresh-contents

```
Making completion list…
Contacting host: elpa.gnu.org:443
Package refresh done
Failed to download ‘gnu’ archive.
```

I have tried

```
‘(“melpa” . “https://melpa.org/packages/“)t)
```

Which does not work.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Sometimes MELPA just don't work, so try again later. But for version 26.2, still useful to have this ```(setq gnutls-algorithm-priority "NORMAL:-VERS-TLS1.3")``` after ```package-initialise```. Since you are new to Emacs, maybe will be more useful to install emacs version 27.2 as described here: https://github.com/d12frosted/homebrew-emacs-plus - this will add more libraries needed for ```org-mode```.

Comment: The quotes surrounding the strings should be double-quote `"` rather than two single quotes `''`, I think.  That said, your error message is reporting a failure to download the default `gnu` archive not `melpa` at all.